# Angular - How to add initialisation params to a service from ngbModule

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular-providers

I am not able to add to a service initialisation params.
It would be perfect to transfer these values from a NgbModule to the service. 
For example in the `provide: [...]` statement.

Comment: I have a question for you. How can you pass these values to NgModule first? Why not just write these values in services constructor?

Comment: the value I want to pass is a static variable from a class and these class I import in the ngbModule, and then it would be very nice to transfer this variable to the service @wannadream

Comment: If it is static, I do not think you have to initiate them in bootstrap. You can just create a class and put some static properties there.